# \autoref subsections in appendix

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, appendices

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\def\sectionautorefname{Section} 
\def\subsectionautorefname{Section} 
\def\appendixautorefname{Appendix}

\begin{document}

First appendix section: \autoref{app sec} 

First appendix subsection: \autoref{app sub}

\appendix
\appendixpage
\section{First appendix section}\label{app sec}
\subsection{First appendix subsection}\label{app sub}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

## Question

Is it possible to `\autoref` a **subsection** in an appendix in the form `Appendix A.1`, instead of `Section A.1` (as shown in the MWE)?

I'm aware a `cleveref` solution given in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5784/18228). If possible, however, I'd like a solution that only involves the `hyperref` package.

Comment: I'd go with `cleveref`.

Comment: @egreg: Is there no way to (re)define `\subsectionautorefname` conditional on whether it's in the appendix or not?

Comment: One should redefine how `hyperref` makes its notes in the `.aux` file. Try and see how it does for changing from `section` to `appendix`; one should extend this also for lower levels.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following applies the appendix name to all section-type labels that sit under `\appendix` or in a `subappendices` environment. Part of the example code borrowed from [“section level” appendices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22827). I've also added some referenced equations to show that these should keep their usual names. It is important to note that when using the `appendices` environment you need to add the `\appendix` too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\def\sectionautorefname{Section}
\def\subsectionautorefname{Section}
\def\appendixautorefname{Appendix}

% begin appendix autoref patch [\autoref subsections in appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149807/autoref-subsections-in-appendix)
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\hyper@makecurrent}{%
    \ifx\Hy@param\Hy@chapterstring
        \let\Hy@param\Hy@chapapp
    \fi
}{%
    \iftoggle{inappendix}{%true-branch
        % list the names of all sectioning counters here
        \@checkappendixparam{chapter}%
        \@checkappendixparam{section}%
        \@checkappendixparam{subsection}%
        \@checkappendixparam{subsubsection}%
        \@checkappendixparam{paragraph}%
        \@checkappendixparam{subparagraph}%
    }{}%
}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}

\newcommand*{\@checkappendixparam}[1]{%
    \def\@checkappendixparamtmp{#1}%
    \ifx\Hy@param\@checkappendixparamtmp
        \let\Hy@param\Hy@appendixstring
    \fi
}
\makeatletter

\newtoggle{inappendix}
\togglefalse{inappendix}

\apptocmd{\appendix}{\toggletrue{inappendix}}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\apptocmd{\subappendices}{\toggletrue{inappendix}}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
% end appendix autoref patch




\begin{document}


First main section: \autoref{main sec} (sectionautorefname).

Subappendix: \autoref{sub}.

Second main section: \autoref{aftersub}.

First appendix section: \autoref{app sec} (appendixautorefname).

First appendix subsection: \autoref{app sub} (appendixautorefname).

Main equation: \autoref{eqn:main}.

Subappendix equation: \autoref{eqn:sub}.

Following equation: \autoref{eqn:aftersub}.

Appendix equation: \autoref{eqn:app}.


\section{foofirst}
\label{main sec}

\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2\label{eqn:main}
\end{equation}

\begin{subappendices}

\subsection{foofirstappendix}
\label{sub}

\begin{equation}
e = mc^2\label{eqn:sub}
\end{equation}

\end{subappendices}

\section{barfirst}
\label{aftersub}

\begin{equation}
g^2 + h^2 = i^2\label{eqn:aftersub}
\end{equation}

\appendix
\appendixpage
\section{First appendix section}\label{app sec}
\subsection{First appendix subsection}\label{app sub}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation} e=mc^2 \label{eqn:app} \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Any way to achieve this without etoolbox?

Comment: @RhysUlerich: Yes, but it is not as robust to new releases of `hyperref`. Simply find the definition `\def\hyper@makecurrent` in `hyperref.sty`, copy and paste in place of the `\patchcmd` and perform the replacement yourself. If you get stuck, let me know. There are also other packages providing commands that can do the same job as `\patchcmd`. Perhaps you could explain why it is that you wish to avoid `etoolbox`, as I understand that to be a fairly common and robust package?

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with `memoir`?

Comment: @rubenvb: I don't immediately see any problem using this with `memoir`. Can you clarify what you have tried and what has gone wrong?

Comment: @cyberSingularity You're right, it works just fine. I was using the `appendices` environment but forgot to add `\appendix` before that. Thanks for this great solution, btw!

Comment: Great fix! Any ideas how to make it compatible with LaTeXML conversion?
It fails with makeatletter part with `Patchcmd is not supported on non-expandable definitions, will not patch` error caused by this code in LaTeXML bindings
https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML/blob/6ee12be9311b90280fdd89f5bdb4fa13ca118785/lib/LaTeXML/Package/etoolbox.sty.ltxml#L1316

Comment: seems it actually works despite error, mentioned above: needed to change second makeatletter to makeatother and get rid of subappendices environment (in TeXLive 2023 it worked for my document)