# {revtex4-1}, {hyperref}, \autoref and \appendix causing "Appendix" to appear as "Section."

Tags: hyperref, revtex, autoref

When using `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{hyperref}` as in the MWE below, the `\autoref` command correctly formats the reference as `Appendix A`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
\label{sec:intro}

See \autoref{apx:details}.

\appendix

\section{Details}
\label{apx:details}

See \autoref{sec:intro}.

\end{document}
```

When I change the document class to `{revtex4-1}`, however, the same example now formats both `\autoref` commands as `Section`.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
\label{sec:intro}

See \autoref{apx:details}.

\appendix

\section{Details}
\label{apx:details}

See \autoref{sec:intro}.

\end{document}
```

Digging into `hyperref.sty`, the main logic to detect appendices is in the `\hyper@makecurrent` command (in particular, this is where `\hy@chapapp` gets used). Thus, I attempted to diagnose the problem by using `{etoolbox}` to debug when this command is given a counter:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\hyper@makecurrent}{
    \message{hyper@makecurrent: #1}
}{}{}
\makeatother
```

For the MWE with `\documentclass{article}`, this gives the log output that one would expect:

```
hyper@makecurrent: section hyper@makecurrent: section
```

For the MWE with `\documentclass{revtex4-1}`, no calls to `\hyper@makecurrent` are generated. This, in particular, defeats the strategy given by [cyberSingularity](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149897), such that including their solution does not cause `\autoref` to correctly format as `Appendix`.

Is it possible to fix this behavior without using `{cleveref}`?